# Select item in the list of item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of div with the same class name. I wonder how to catch exactly which div client click on it by using jquery. I try many way in many times but I couldn''t figure out. Please help me because I''m newbie in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){
  $(this); //This is the clicked div
});
```

**Edit:** In response to your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712519/select-item-in-the-list-of-item-using-jquery/712541#712541)

You can get all the radio button selected doing something like this:

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
   $(this); // Checked radio button element(s)...
});
```

There you can access the element value with `$(this).val()`, or also the name attribute, with `$(this).attr('name')`.

Recommended lecture:

- [API/Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Use "this" in your click callback:

`$("div.nameofclass").click(function(){$(this).css('border', '1px solid red')});`